# Installing Joomla - Removing installation folder

Tags: installation

Ever since I started using Joomla (in the mid 1.5 days), the `installation` directory must be deleted once Joomla has been successfully installed, but my question is, why must we click a button to delete it? Is there a reason why this is not done automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're using something that is not a official release (i.e. all the testing packages and the latest staging packages on github) you don't need to remove the install directory (the check is commented out). This means all you need to do is delete configuration.php and you can just start the installation proceedure again. The risk is people could accidental commit the removed install directory, and it just becomes a pain for everyone involved to fix it up.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say I know the answer, but my guess is that it's a last chance to re-run the installation (by deleting `configuration.php`) in case something went wrong, the wrong database was used, or for any other reason not caught by the error handling.

Deleting the folder automatically could cause it to be removed when it shouldn't.

There's also a chance, as @Farahmand points out, that there are other files in the folder (although there shouldn't be), maybe from other software.

Comment: I often use it to rerun installations and quite like that Joomla doesn't presume to eliminate it

Answer (score 0):

Because few people may put some files temporarily anywhere like Joomla installation directory and don't want them to be deleted automatically. It may be a rare condition but Joomla should consider all probabilities!

Comment: Would you not be better using the /tmp folder for such things?

Comment: @johnny_s - Yes, but a beginner may not know about `/tmp` directory. Also the files in `tmp` directories may be deleted automatically by some cron jobs.